# Java select from a pool of random numbers

Tags: java, random

I'm making a bingo like program in java, I was wondering if it was a ll possible to select a number from a pool, then have it cross it out. I was thinking of putting the 75 (bingo numbers) into an array then have it select it from there, but i cant seem to find a way to get rid of that number once it's selected. for example, i only want to call the number 55 ONCE, then have it gone, or non-accessible from the pool once it's called by my random function.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Create a `boolean[]`, set to true when you get a number, ignore if you already had found.

Answer (score 4):

1. Generate array 1..75.
2. Shuffle.
3. Read one at the time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 1):

(deleted my previous answer because I misread the question)

Easiest way I can think of to do this is to store them in an `ArrayList`, track the size and feed that into a random number generator to randomly access an index and remove after use.

Answer (score 1):

Place all 75 numbers into an array.

Call `Arrays.shuffle()` on the array.

Read the array in-order.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Collection of Integers

   Randomly generate an int with a range from zero to collection.size()-1

   Remove the item at the index of the random int from step 2. This item is the number you call and will no longer be selectable.